# NSManagedObject with mandatory relationship

Tags: objective-c, core-data, entity-relationship, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Is it possible for a managed object to have a relationship with 'optional' unchecked?

If so, how can I insert it without having validateForInsert: fail?
I want the relationship to be mandatory but I am unable to establish a connection between the current and another object before inserting it because the two objects I want to connect are in different contexts.

**Concrete Example:**
I generally have one MOC. Let's say I have a `Person` saved in the context.
Now I want to create a new one, so I instantiate a `Person` but do **not** insert it into the context yet. When the user picks a brother from some table view and I set the 'brother' property, the inverse relationship would attempt to establish a connection between the object saved in the MOC and the one that does not exist in the MOC yet, which would cause the app to crash.
*My Question:* if the 'brother' relationship would **not** be optional, could I even create and insert a new person?

Comment: Please show how you initialize each of the NSManagedObjects that you are referring to. You should be initializing with the method `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:` which immediately associates the object with a managed object context (but does not save it to the persistent store)

Comment: That's what I did. Check my answer though, I already fixed the problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a dumb question of myself.

Of course you can insert an object into the context without causing an error. You can then set up the (mandatory) relationships.
The validation of relationships and properties only occurs when actually trying to save the context.

In my app however, I did not insert the entity until the 'NewItemVC' finished. I called -validateForInsert: on the object being created to check if it's valid an enable/disable the done button.
Since I cannot establish the mandatory relationship without inserting it, this is not a good idea, I gotta think of something new.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that contexts are used to share a common awareness of the changes to a persistent store. You can have two contexts referring to the same persistent store.

So, for example, if you have an NSFetchedResultsController, you can make it receive notifications that the managed object context has changed. You might have two persistent stores so you can confine notification about some changes. (A simple, and maybe not too realistic, example would be a search results list in one context, but favorites list in another context. You app could change an an item in the results list by making it a favorite. You may only want that notification to go to the context that the favorites list and its fetched results controller are referring to, assuming that the results list is not affected anyway. So two contexts make sense here. But both contexts refer to the same persistent store.)

More importantly, if the objects being referred to in two contexts are contained in the same persistent store, they still have intact all of their relationships and the process for managing those relationships.

So I don't understand your statement that the objects aare in different contexts. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Check my question again, I added an example.